# After I resurrect my follower he/she stops following me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After using the command `ressurect 1` after Ghorbash had died in battle, he stopped following me, and now I can't get him to follow me again. He's acting like he did before I convinced him to follow me in the first place. 

Is there anything I can do, or am I going to have to find another good follower?

Comment: Mjoll! She's invincible!

Comment: A dragon killed her earlier on in the game I think.

Comment: No it didn't. She's required so she can't actually die. She gets into a 'downed' state, but can't die.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me, it's because for some weird reason, the follower's relationship to the player character has decreased. Most followers will only follow you if you are at a certain positive level of relationship with them.

If playing on the PC, to increase your relationship level to Ghorbash the Iron Hand, you can use the following console commands:

> prid 19930
>   setrelationshiprank player 3

OR

> player.setrelationshiprank 19930 3

Note that the '19930' in the above console commands is Ghorbash the Iron Hand's [RefID](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs). If you have a different follower, you can search for your follower's RefID at the [UESP wiki's "*Followers*" article](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) and replace '19930' with the appropriate RefID.

Another method to target instead of using `prid <refID>` is to open up the console and then click on your follower. If done correctly, your follower's RefID should show up on the screen. This is the same as entering `prid <RefID>` in the console.

Th above console commands will set your follower's relationship to you as 'ally'. You can also change the '3' in the console command to '4', if you want to set your follower as a 'lover'. That will also allow you to marry them.

The conversation option to ask your follower to follow you again should now appear.

More info on console commands here: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console