# I used the ressurect command on one of my followers but now they don't act like a follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My follower Faendal died and I wanted him to still be my follower so I used the resurrect command but now he doesn't let me say "I need you to follow me" and instead he acts like I didn't give Camilla the letter in his favor. How do I make him my follower again?

Edit: He doesn't even let me train in archery.

Comment: With some console magic you might be able to get him to want to hang out with you again, but why don't you just revert to an older save file?

Comment: @Joachim well I can't really do that because I've done a lot of stuff that I don't want to redo and the save state I thought had him didn't have him alive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After I resurrected Ghorbash the Iron Hand he stopped following me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79922/after-i-resurrected-ghorbash-the-iron-hand-he-stopped-following-me). I started out writing an answer, as I couldn't find duplicates at first, but I stumbled upon this when searching. I hope that will help you, @DerekPulley!